# Using an array variable in WHERE NOT IN -like clause

Tags: postgresql

I have declared an array variable as

```
select array(select "account_id" from [some where clause]) as negateArray;
```

Note that I return a single column. Now I need to use it in another WHERE-clause that should mean: **do NOT include data if account_id matches any of found in negateArray**.

I write something like

```
select * from [some other where clause] WHERE (account_id NOT IN ANY(negateArray));
```

but I am getting a syntax error. What would be the correct way to write the condition for PostgreSQL?

Comment: `select array(select "account_id" from [some where clause]) as negateArray;` this not creates variable.

Comment: @OtoShavadze could you please suggest better syntax for storing the first select into something that I can use in second one?

Comment: Do you use procedure/function for this? or this is pure SQL ?

Comment: pure SQL only, I am fixing a legacy query

Comment: Then no need variable, you can do that using single sql statement, see EDIT in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to let the optimizer do its best - convert the `not in` condition to `left [outer] join`. Here is an equivalent SQL-only version rewrite:

```sql
   select  t2.*
     from  outer_table t2 
left join  (select account_id from inner_table where [some where clause on inner_table]) t1
       on  t2.account_id = t1.account_id 
    where  [some other where clause on outer_table]
      AND  t1.account_id IS NULL;
```

`t1.account_id IS NULL` does the `not in` job.

**Edit**
Equivalent but shorter (and probably more efficient) using `[inner] join` and inverted condition:

```sql
select  t2.*
  from  outer_table t2 
  join  (select account_id from inner_table where NOT [some where clause on inner_table]) t1
    on  t2.account_id = t1.account_id 
 where  [some other where clause on outer_table];
```

Comment: yes, this brings down the complexity a great deal. Excellent suggestion. Though I would be extra careful on formulating the condition on the Join in your 2nd example. I suspect that inverted condition edit can be tricky, at least the correct reply I got when using the first example, but it could be just me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use variables, then you need to do this using procedure/function.

First, define variable as `negateArray int[]`

Then try:

```
select array(select "account_id" from [some where clause]) INTO negateArray;
```

and then:

```
select * from [some other where clause] WHERE (account_id <> ANY(negateArray));
```

EDIT

For "pure" SQL, you don't need variable, just use query like this:

```
select * from [some other where clause] -- your second query
WHERE account_id NOT IN( 
        select "account_id" from [some where clause] -- your first query
);
```

Comment: I am trying to reduce complexity of the query that presently has that NOT IN clause. It shows some huge cost with Nested Loop Anti Join. I could however declare a function I guess.

Comment: Is `account_id` indexed for  outer query ?

Comment: @AskarIbragimov `NOT IN` and `<> ANY` are equivalent in complexity. Look for adequate indexing to support such queries.